# Update a table from dynamic dropdownlist from a lookup table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I don't know if this is due to poor db design or not but I have been struggling since last night to update some records from by selecting the values of records to be updated from a dynamically populated dropdownlist from a lookup table.

Essentially, we have three tables called Courses, Instructors and CourseInstructor tables.

CourseInstructor table is a bridge table between Courses and Instructor tables.

So, when adding courses and instructors to their various tables, their foreign keys are automatically added to the bridge table.

This seems to work fine so far.

However, users are having difficulties making changes to these tables.

For instance, if a user wishes to replace one instructor with another, she has not been to do so for far. After an update, the message indicates successful update the instructor names don't change.

Any ideas what I could have done wrong with the code below?

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Instructor">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInstructors" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SubjectDataSource"
                    DataTextField="InstructorName" DataValueField="InstructorId">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInstructors" runat="server" Text='<% #Bind("InstructorName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceloc" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConn %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT locationId, Location FROM Locations order by location asc"></asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConnectionString %>" 
     UpdateCommand = "Update tblCourseInstructor Set CourseId = @CourseId where (CourseId =@CourseId) Update tblCourseInstructor set InstructorId=@InstructorId where (instructorId=@instructorId and courseId = @courseId)"
     SelectCommand="select l.locationid,c.CourseId, i.instructorId,CourseName, i.instructorname, dbo.fnFormatDate(t.trainingDates, 'MON/DD/YYYY') trainingDates, t.trainingTime,CourseDescription from Courses c, tblLocations l, TrainingDates t, Instructors i, CourseInstructor ci where l.locationid = c.locationid and c.dateId = t.dateId and i.instructorid =  ci.instructorId and c.courseid=ci.courseid and YEAR(t.trainingDates) = YEAR(getDate())"
                   FilterExpression="LocationId = '{0}'" >
<FilterParameters>
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlLocation" Name="LocationId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
 </FilterParameters>              
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CourseId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="instructorId" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SubjectDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBConn %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT instructorId, InstructorName FROM dbo.Instructors order by InstructorName">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>   


Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
        Dim ddAssigned As DropDownList = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlInstructors"), DropDownList)
        e.NewValues("instructorId") = ddAssigned.SelectedValue
        SubjectDataSource.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Comment: UpdateCommand should check for old value in where condition and update new values. However it always using new values in both set and where clause.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota, now I am officially confused!

The user selects instructor (@instructorId) from the dropdown which is from the lookup table and updates instructorId from another table.

How are they both new? I am not challenging you; I am just curious.

At the top, I have updated my code with the update I was using on codebehind and this gives me an error that says, `Updating is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless UpdateCommand is specified.`

How do I fixt this one?